# How to find the ideal price for a product (provides highest profit) by searching a range of prices

Tags: python, python-3.x

```
def profit():
    price = input('Enter a price: ')
    demand = 650 - (10 * price)
    cost_per_item = 35
    firm_profit = (price - cost_per_item) * demand
    return firm_profit
```

How can one search through a range of prices to find the price that provides the highest profit based on this relationship between demand and the product?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If this problem uses discreet units (for example, if you must use integers) then you just use a loop to try every possibility from a price of 0 to a price which would produce a zero demand (65 in this case, because 650 - 10*65 = 0).

I would start by moving the price from an input to a parameter of the function, so:

```
def profit(price):
     demand = 650 - (10 * price)
     cost_per_item = 35
     firm_profit = (price - cost_per_item) * demand
     return firm_profit
```

Then we define a variable to pass through the function and increment it to try every possibility:

```
price = 0
best_price = 0
increment = 1
while price<65:
    if profit(price)>profit(best_price):
        best_price = price
    price += increment
```

If you end up needing to use a decimal increment, you might want to use the decimal module to avoid some strange, floating point behavior.

Answer (score 1):

It is really a mathematical problem. Your formula for profit is:

```
profit = (p - c) * d = (p - c) * (650 - 10 * p)
```

where I abbreviated `p` for `price`, `c` for `cost_per_item`, `d` for `demand`.

To maximize `profit` all that you need to do is to find the value of `p` for which derivative of `profit` with regard to `p` is zero:

```
d(profit) / d(p) = 650 + 10*c - 20*p = 0 =>
pmax = (650 + 10*c) / 20
```

If you need to pick a price from a list of possible values, pick the one closest to `pmax` (since `profit` is a parabola with regard to `p` and so it is symmetric around the vertical line passing through `pmax`).

Therefore, if you *do* have a list of prices (I suppose this is what you mean by "range of values") contained in a *list* **`prices`**, then:

```
best_price = min(abs(x - pmax) for x in prices)
```

where `pmax` was computed earlier.

Answer (score 1):

Another possibility: first define a `demand` function, next a `profit` function and eventually use the `max` builtin applied to a generator expression that produces couples of values `(profit, price)` that `max`, by default, compares taking into account the  first value in the couple.

```
>>> def demand_01(price):
...    return 650-10*price
>>> def profit(price, cost, demand):
...    return (price-cost)*demand(price)

>>> print(max((profit(price, 35, demand_01), price) for price in (39.95, 69.90, 99.00))
(1239.9750000000008, 39.95)
```

The advantage of definining separately a `demand` and a `profit` function and using `max` lies in

1. the possibility of using whatever mathematical definition (even piecewise), w/o involving the differentiability of the `profit`function and
2. the possibility of definining different `demand` functions to explore the sensitivity of the results on different assumptions.

---

*Addendum*

To have the best price and the associated maximum profit you can *unpack* the result returned by the `max` builtin:

```
max_profit, best_price = max( (profit(price, 35, demand_01), price)
    for price in (...))
```